# Django Querying a Choice Field

Tags: python, django

On my website I display individual user created listings, when a user creates a listing some of the fields are multiple choice and thus I have stored these in a list. Here is an example of how I would typically have stored this list

List -

```
area_code_choice = (
    ('1', '021'),
    ('2', '027'),
    ('3', '022'),
    ('4', 'Other')
)
```

The problem with this is when I try to display their choice my query returns the '1' rather than the '021', I did try making both sides the same so it would be ('021', '021') however I felt that probably wasn't the best way to do it.

HTML Template -

```
({{ joblistings.area_code }})
```

View -

```
job_listing = JobListing.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

If someone could please advise me on how to get the other side of the choice list that would be great! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get_FOO_display() in template

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

`{{ joblistings.get_area_code_display }}`